# Java parsing issue on cast method reference?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

If the parser encounters a method reference to a cast, i.e.

```
... .stream().map(MyClass.class::cast). ...
```

it fails with "Unable to parse source file".

```
[ERROR] [15:58:25.853] Unable to parse source file : ...
[ERROR] [15:58:25.855] Parse error at line .. column .. failed to match all of: 
spacing DOT AT LBRK INC DEC STAR DIV MOD PLUS MINUS SL BSR SR GE GT LE LT 
INSTANCEOF EQUAL NOTEQUAL AND HAT OR ANDAND OROR QUERY EQU PLUSEQU MINUSEQU 
STAREQU DIVEQU ANDEQU OREQU HATEQU MODEQU SLEQU SREQU BSREQU COMMA RPAR
```

When changing this into pre Java 8 code it works.

This looks like a bug in the Sonarqube maven plugin parser, doesn't it?

Can someone point me to a place or give me a hint where to fix this issue?

As a side note: I've already created an issue in the [codehaus jira](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSONAR-115), but was told that wasn't the right place...

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the sonar-java plugin. Not in the maven plugin (which is just a convenient way to execute sonar-java plugin). Would you be able to tell us which version of this plugin you use and execute your analysis with a -e flag so you can provide a more complete stacktrace ? Thanks.

Comment: @benzonico I've created a minimum test project to reproduce the error. I already had the idea that the source of the error was in the sonar-java plugin, but couldn't reproduce it (maybe it has been already fixed). I then created a jenkins job to reproduce the problem, it fails, but am not sure where to apply the '-e'?

Comment: FYI: the test project that fails when using the jenkins sonar plugin is here: https://github.com/dhiller/sonar-java-method-reference-parsing-bug

Comment: Which version of the java plugin are you using ?

Comment: java-squid 3.2 for invocation of the AST parser, and as I said, I can't tell you what version the sonar-maven-plugin is using, the plugin version for jenkins is sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar. Can you elaborate on where to apply the '-e'? Do you mean in voking maven from the command line?

Comment: @benzonico did I miss something? Do you need more information?